# customizing a scaffold controller-MVC5 Controller with views,using Entity Framework

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am using using Visual Studio 2013 and I have created code Templates and copied all the templates from C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web\Mvc\Scaffolding\Templates

I want to customize the scaffold item for controller- MVC5 Controller with views,using Entity Framework.
How do I check which one of the templates in code templates folder corresponds to this

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed MvcScaffolding ? If not, just type the following at your Package Manage Console:

```
Install-Package MvcScaffolding
```

You can customize pretty much everything, if you type the command below you are going to be able to customize your controller:

```
Scaffold CustomTemplate Controller ControllerWithRepository
```

A new folder will came up on your solution, check the image below:

[image]

To see the whole list of scaffolders available, just type:

```
Get-Scaffolder
```